event.StopPropogation not working in react
I am having some weird issue which I want to know why that is happening.
I am using MUI and React. Here if I click on my menu icon (which opens the menu) even if I add the stopPropogation. It still fire's my top most paper element onClick handler. Tried the preventDefault too but the immediate parents (Box & Stack element) onClick is not getting triggered. It's kind of jumping directly to parent.
Code
// react
import { useState } from "react";
// mui
import {
  Paper,
  Card,
  CardContent,
  Typography,
  CardActions,
  Menu,
  MenuItem,
  Skeleton,
  Stack,
  Box,
  IconButton,
} from "@mui/material";
import DeleteForeverIcon from "@mui/icons-material/DeleteForever";
// components
import Chip from "../base/chip";
import { Button } from "../base";
import { ProjectInfo } from "@/utils/types";
import { format } from "date-fns";
import { MoreHoriz } from "@mui/icons-material";

function ProjectMenu({
  anchorEl,
  open,
  handleClose,
  handleOpenDeleteModal,
  // handleOpenEditModal,
  projectId,
}: {
  anchorEl: Element | null;
  projectId: string | number;
  open: boolean;
  handleClose: () => void;
  handleOpenDeleteModal: (projectId: string | number) => void;
  // handleOpenEditModal: (projectId: string | number) => void;
}) {
  const menuOptions = [
    {
      title: "Delete Vault",
      handler: (projectId: string | number) => {
        handleOpenDeleteModal(projectId);
        handleClose();
      },
      icon: (
        <DeleteForeverIcon sx={{ mr: 2, color: "customColors.error.main" }} />
      ),
      sx: { color: "customColors.error.main" },
    },
  ];

  return (
    <Menu
      anchorEl={anchorEl}
      open={open}
      onClose={handleClose}
      anchorOrigin={{
        vertical: "top",
        horizontal: "left",
      }}
      transformOrigin={{
        vertical: "top",
        horizontal: "left",
      }}
      slotProps={{
        paper: {
          sx: {
            borderRadius: 2,
          },
        },
      }}
    >
      {menuOptions.map((option, index) => (
        <MenuItem
          key={`option-${index}`}
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.stopPropagation();
            option.handler(projectId);
          }}
          sx={{
            fontSize: 14,
            fontWeight: "normal",
            lineHeight: "1.25rem",
            borderBottom: "1px solid #F2F4F7",
            ":last-child": {
              borderBottom: "1px solid transparent",
            },
            ...option.sx,
          }}
        >
          {option.icon} {option.title}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Menu>
  );
}

export default function ProjectCard({
  projectInfo,
  disableMenu,
  handleDelete,
  handleEdit,
  handleView,
  onClick,
}: {
  projectInfo: ProjectInfo;
  disableMenu?: boolean;
  onClick: () => void;
  handleDelete: (projectId: string | number) => void;
  handleEdit: (projectId: string | number) => void;
  handleView: (projectId: string | number) => void;
}) {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState<null | Element>(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  return (
    <Paper
      elevation={0}
      sx={{
        boxShadow: "0px 2px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08)",
        borderRadius: 2.5,
        bgcolor: "background.paper",
        cursor: "pointer",
        transition: "transform .2s ease-in, border-color .2s ease-in",
        border: "2px solid transparent",
        ":hover": {
          transform: "scale(1.01)",
          border: "2px solid",
          borderColor: "customColors.primary.main",
        },
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        justifyContent: "space-between",
        flex: 1,
        height: "100%",
      }}
      onClick={() => {
        alert("bubblepaper");
      }}
    >
      <Stack
        sx={{
          p: 3,
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          justifyContent: "space-between",
          position: "relative",
          height: "100%",
        }}
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.stopPropagation();
          e.preventDefault();
          alert("bubblestack");
        }}
      >
        <Box
          onClick={(e) => {
            // setAnchorEl(e.currentTarget);
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("bubblebox");
          }}
          sx={{
            position: "absolute",
            top: 5,
            right: 5,
            border: "1px solid red",
          }}
        >
          {!disableMenu && (
            <IconButton
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.stopPropagation();
                setAnchorEl(e.currentTarget);
              }}
            >
              <MoreHoriz />
            </IconButton>
          )}
        </Box>
        <Stack>
          <Typography
            sx={{
              fontSize: 22,
              fontWeight: 500,
              lineHeight: "normal",
              letterSpacing: "-0.32px",
              color: "customColors.text.greyBlack",
              whiteSpace: "nowrap",
              textOverflow: "ellipsis",
              width: "calc(100% - 30px)",
              overflow: "hidden",
              mr: 1,
            }}
          >
            {projectInfo?.name
              ? projectInfo?.name?.charAt(0)?.toUpperCase() +
                projectInfo?.name?.slice(1)
              : "-"}
          </Typography>
          <Typography
            mb={0.5}
            sx={{
              fontSize: 17,
              fontWeight: 600,
              lineHeight: "1.75rem",
              letterSpacing: "-0.25px",
              color: "customColors.text.greyBlack",
              whiteSpace: "nowrap",
              textOverflow: "ellipsis",
              width: "calc(100% - 30px)",
              overflow: "hidden",
            }}
          >
            {projectInfo?.metadata?.client_name
              ? projectInfo?.metadata?.client_name?.charAt(0)?.toUpperCase() +
                projectInfo?.metadata?.client_name?.slice(1)
              : "-"}
          </Typography>
          <Typography
            mb={2}
            sx={{ color: "customColors.text.grey2", flex: 1 }}
            className="clip-multiline-text2"
          >
            {projectInfo?.description
              ? projectInfo?.description?.charAt(0)?.toUpperCase() +
                projectInfo?.description?.slice(1)
              : "-"}
          </Typography>
        </Stack>

        <Stack gap={2}>
          <Stack>
            <Stack direction="row" alignItems="center" gap={1}>
              <Typography
                sx={{ color: "customColors.text.grey2", mb: 0.5 }}
                component="span"
              >
                Status:{" "}
              </Typography>{" "}
              <Chip
                label="Public"
                size="small"
                sx={{
                  bgcolor: "customColors.error.bg",
                  color: "customColors.error.main",
                  fontWeight: "bold",
                  borderRadius: "3px",
                }}
                iconColor="customColors.error.main"
              />
            </Stack>
            <Typography sx={{ color: "customColors.text.grey2", mt: 0.5 }}>
              Last updated:{" "}
              {projectInfo?.created_at
                ? format(projectInfo?.created_at, "dd/MM/yyyy")
                : ""}
            </Typography>
          </Stack>
          <Stack direction="row" gap={2}>
            <Button
              variant="outlined"
              onClick={() => {
                handleEdit(projectInfo.id);
              }}
            >
              Edit{" "}
            </Button>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              onClick={() => {
                handleView(projectInfo.id);
              }}
            >
              View{" "}
            </Button>
          </Stack>
        </Stack>
      </Stack>

      <ProjectMenu
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        open={open}
        projectId={projectInfo?.id}
        handleClose={() => setAnchorEl(null)}
        handleOpenDeleteModal={(projectId) => handleDelete(projectId)}
        // handleOpenEditModal={(projectId) => handleEdit(projectId)}
      />
    </Paper>
  );
}

export function ProjectCardSkeleton() {
  return (
    <Card
      elevation={0}
      sx={{
        boxShadow: "0px 2px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08)",
        borderRadius: 2.5,
        bgcolor: "background.paper",
        cursor: "pointer",
        transition: "transform .2s ease-in, border-color .2s ease-in",
        border: "2px solid transparent",
        ":hover": {
          transform: "scale(1.01)",
          border: "2px solid",
          borderColor: "customColors.primary.main",
        },
      }}
    >
      <CardContent sx={{ p: 3, pb: 0 }}>
        <Skeleton
          variant="rounded"
          width="70%
        "
        />
        <Skeleton variant="rounded" width="55%" sx={{ mt: 1 }} />
        <Skeleton variant="rounded" width="100%" height={50} sx={{ mt: 2 }} />
        <Stack direction="row" alignItems="center" gap={2}>
          <Skeleton width="20%" height={30} />
          <Skeleton width="30%" height={30} />
        </Stack>

        <Skeleton width="70%" height={30} />
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions sx={{ px: 3, pb: 4 }}>
        <Skeleton width="20%" height={50} />
        <Skeleton width="20%" height={50} />
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
}



I already tried using stopPropogation and preventDefaults on immidiate parents.
